# With Yosemite pop-over doesn't work when holding keys down anymore

Tags: keyboard, macos

I always used the accented character pop-over menu often, by holding a key for a second or two.  Now, with Yosemite suddenly all I get is something like:

> Resumeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

When I want the chance to type:

> Resumé

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Try adding another keyboard like French to your list in system prefs/keyboard/input sources and restart.

Comment: Thank you.  Adding French and restarting did the trick.  It was driving me crazy. :)

Answer (score 1):

Resume

[image: accent]

Maybe it is disabled for some reason ?

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false
```

to enable copy paste following in your Terminal app located in the utility folder.

```
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool true
```